# How do I decode a json dumps txt with unicode attributes?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, unicode, amazon-dynamodb

[image]

Sorry, had issues with indentation of code when posting this question so just took a photo instead.

Comment: Try this: json.loads(UserModel.dumps(), encoding='utf8')

Comment: Please include code and descriptions as text, not as image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
json.dumps(json.loads(UserModels.dumps()))
```

Comment: Thats wont work, JSON is not accessible as dictionary in python and Jinja2

Comment: is there any other method I can use to get the users from the dynamodb and display in in a html page?

Comment: I'm now getting this error:     print x[1]['attributes']['firstname']['S']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: json.dumps(json.loads(UserModels.dumps())) seem to work with getting rid of unicode type thanks